# How prove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{i+j}{i^2+j^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\ln{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-sum

show that: this limit
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{i+j}{i^2+j^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\ln{2}$$

My try: 
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\dfrac{i}{n}+\dfrac{j}{n}}{\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{j}{n}\right)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}dxdy?$$

This idea is true? and have other methods?

Comment: The obvious problem with the double integral is that it has problems near $(0,0)$, so that this is an improper integral.

Comment: The function is $O(1/(x+y))$, so the singularity is under control for purposes of integration, a $1/r$ blowup on area $r^2$ for $r \to 0$.  @ThomasAndrews

Comment: I think that the methoid you propose in you post is both simple and elegant. I tried a few thinks, in particular eveluating the most inner summation for a given value of $i$; this leads to awful results involving for PolyGamma functions. As a result, the outer summation cannot be expressed analytically. As a conclusion from my side, I enjoy your method and I congratulate you for its simplicity.

Answer (score 6):

Evaluation of the integral(after Thomas Andrews's calculation)

$$
\int_0^1 \log(1+y^2) dy= y\log(1+y^2)|_0^1 -\int_0^1 \frac{2y^2}{1+y^2} dy$$
$$=\log 2-\int_0^1 \frac{2y^2+2-2}{1+y^2} dy$$
$$=\log 2 - 2 + \frac{\pi}{2} $$

$$-\int_0^1 \log (y^2) dy = -\int_0^1 2\log y dy = 2\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = 2$$

Hence, the integral all together is 
$$\log 2 + \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Application of Stolz-Cesaro:

If we can prove that the limit exists
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i+n}{i^2+n^2} +\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{n+j}{n^2+j^2}\right)  $$
then the answer is the same as the limit.

Evaluation of this limit requires integral, but this time not a 'double integral'.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i+n}{i^2+n^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ \frac{i}{n}+1}{\frac{i^2}{n^2}+1} \frac{1}{n}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{x+1}{x^2+1} dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\log 2.$$
The other part can be dealt similarly, it has the same value as above. Thus, all together the answer becomes 
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+\log 2.$$

Comment: How was Stolz-Cesaro used to get from a two-variable sum to a pair of one-variable sums?

Comment: $\lim a_n/n = \lim (a_n-a_{n-1})$ if the limit on the right exists. Here $a_n=\sum_1^n\sum_1^n (i+j)/(i^2+j^2)$.

Comment: Why is @zyx asking about Stolz-Cesaro? Someone asked about that in my answer, too, yet it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: In a comment it was stated that there was a hint to solve the problem with Stolz-Cesaro, this answer used it, and my question (now answered) was to which pair of sequences the theorem was applied.  @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @zyx Where did the OP say that? Was the comment deleted? Why didn't anybody suggest that OP put that in the question?

Comment: I meant the comment under your answer. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Not the same user as OP, however. @zyx I assumed that answerer was also referring to the same comment that you were referring to, but if there was another comment from the OP, maybe it was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

[Incomplete answer]

Probably a good place to start is to note: $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy = \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$$

by symmetry, assuming the integral exists.

So you really need to compute $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\,dx \,dy$$

That looks easier to compute.

$$\int_0^1\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} dx = \log (1+y^2)-\log(y^2) = \log(1+y^{-2})$$

That leads to $$\int_0^1 \log(1+y^{-2})\,dy$$

Not sure if that's going to do any good.

Comment: It is said can use  Stolz–Ces`aro lemma,and then can use without Double integral

Answer (score 2):

(1) Integral is finite.

The function in the integral is $\leq \frac{2}{x+y}$. The integral of $1/(x+y)$ on the square is bounded, because $\frac{1}{x+y} \in [N,N+1)$ for points in the square with $x+y \in [1/(N+1), 1/N]$ is (for large $N$) a trapezoid with height approximately $1/N^2$ and width of approximately $1/N$, for a total contribution to the integral of about $N \times \frac{1}{N^3} (1 + o(1)) \sim \frac{1}{N^2} $.  This converges when summed on integer $N \geq n_0$.

(2) Sum converges to the integral.

The sum is a "minimum" Riemann sum for the integral on a partition of the square into $n^2$ equal small.  The "maximum" Riemann sum on the same squares except the one containing $(0,0)$ (whose contribution to the sum and to the integral both converge to $0$, and can be ignored) is the same sum for $i,j < n$, plus a small modification along the boundary of the square ($ij=0$ or $i=n$ or $j=n$). These changes to the sum are essentially line integrals of a the function along the sides of the square, weighted by $1/n$, and the modifications go to $0$.

(3) Evaluation of integral.

This can be done using polar coordinates, and maybe by easier methods.  I did not work it out, since parts 1+2 already identified what the limit "is" and showed convergence.

Comment: (Integral now done in one of the other answers)